# WebDriverWait - Timeout isn't respected with UWP

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, uwp

I'm writing some code for automation test to UWP (Universal Windows Platform) and sometimes I need to wait for a certain element. But I'm coming across with the following problem: the timeout always breaks less than 60 seconds (40~60 seconds).

**Function Call:**

```
waitForElementName(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120).Seconds, "abcde");
```

**Function:**

```
protected static WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> desktopSession;

public static void waitForElementName(long timeout, string elementName)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(desktopSession, new TimeSpan(timeout));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(OpenQA.Selenium.By.Name(elementName)));     
}
```

In this case, I want to wait 120 seconds for the element. But always in 40~60 seconds, the timeout breaks, and the debugger comes with the following message:

> Message: Test method threw exception:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: An element could not be located on
>   the page using the given search parameters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem using 2 different drivers and changing the **timeout** and **ImplictlyWait()** values.

1 - For access the windows elements, I declare the driver without the timeout parameter (if you don`t declare it, the default timeout is 60 seconds) and setting the ImplictlyWait() to 10 seconds:

```
protected static WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> desktopSession;

desktopSession = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(WindowsApplicationDriverUrl), desktopCapabilities);

desktopSession.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

2 - For the WaitFor() methods, I declare the driver passing the timeout and ImplictlyWait values, like the following code:

```
public static void WaitForElementByName(TimeSpan timeout, string elementName)
{
    WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> driver = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri(WindowsApplicationDriverUrl), desktopCapabilities, timeout);

    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(timeout);

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(OpenQA.Selenium.By.Name(elementName)));
}
```

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, you have to pass the WindowsDriver to the WebDriverWait along with set timeout using 'TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout)' , for example.

```
protected static WindowsDriver<WindowsElement> desktopSession;

public static void waitForElementName(long timeout, string elementName)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(desktopSession,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(OpenQA.Selenium.By.Name(elementName)));     
}
```

I hope this helps.

Thanks

Comment: I didn't understand your suggestion. How can i pass the driver to a WebDriverWait?

Can you write a code example for me, please?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I have provided a sample as part of my answer. Basically, you are passing in new TimeSpan(timeout). This should be TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout) so all together it should look like this .WebDriverWait(desktopSession,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout)); I hope this helps. I am happy to help with anyother questions If it does help please mark the answers as correct. Thanks